# How to check for Is Not Null in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, null, vba

Hi I have the following expression. I'm trying to say "if the second field Is Not Null". Can you help.

Thanks

```
=Iif((Fields!approved.Value = "N" & Fields!W_O_Count.Value IsNotNull), "Red", "Transparent")
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use `Not IsNull(Fields!W_O_Count.Value)`

So:

```
=IIF(Fields!approved.Value = "N" & Not IsNull(Fields!W_O_Count.Value)), "Red", "Transparent")
```

Answer (score 19):

you can do like follows. Remember, IsNull is a function which returns TRUE if the parameter passed to it is null, and false otherwise.

```
Not IsNull(Fields!W_O_Count.Value)
```